Sports' Formations, Plays, Game Plans, Profiles, that coaches create & use with players
Can sports' (Thinking of FootBall, but cannot see how this would not apply to all sports; Few popular enough examples, for non-FootBall-Sports readers.
At least in the sport of FootBall with the below parts of coaching & playing there are no successful secrets that stay secrets
Heck, I been to coaching clinics where they are freely shared. I also no longer thinking just about patenting or Etc. to protect the below in Real World FB -sports- Galaxy.
Mainly thinking about Internet FB galaxy, with thinking of the whole of The FB universe.
As of now, thankfully, the Real World FB galaxy is not seeing what are infront of their faces)
Formations (offensive- Shotgun, I, One-Back, Two-Backs & Defense- 4-3 <Front/Defensive Linemen-LineBackers>-4 , 3-4 <Front/DLmen-LBs>-4 ),
Plays (in their entirity- offense- Hail Mary, Sweep & defense Blitzes,Cover 2),
Play Books (where all the plays are grouped in a manageable/useable amount & according to wanting to be used in a Play Sheets, Profiles & Game Plans).
&
Play Sheets (the during practices-games reminder sheets of what is in the Game Plans),
Profiles (created for how, when & Etc. to use of Formations, Plays, Play Books & Play Sheets, of an Offense & Defense)
Game Plans (Profiles for specific opponents),
Offenses & Defenses (All of the others together & easy to use name applied,
To organize the many of Offenses & Defenses & communicate quickly to all involved- Formations, Plays, Game Plans & Play Sheets, Game Plans & Profiles together as one that can apply
&
There are specific Offenses & Defenses for specific opponents
Examples, popular enough that we all can think of right away, like the West Coast Offense <football media credits Bill Walsh with it's creation- https://culturecrossfire.com/sports/football/west-coast-offense/>
&
Bear Defense <football media credits Buddy Ryan with it's creation- https://profootballmania.com/2022/01/14/buddy-ryan-the-creator-of-the-1985-bears-defense/>)
All of the above that coaches create, teach to & use with players,
be patented or protected legally in some other way(s)?

Your long comment that was posted in the place of an answer has been deleted as “not an answer”.  SE sites are not forums.

Game playing strategy will probably be labeled as "certain methods of organizing human activity”. Patent examiners use this phrase to reject claims as abstract. The quote is from a SCOTUS case but appears in that case with no clear idea what it should mean.
You are very unlikely to get a patent on this type of subject matter. I understand teams try to keep playbooks a "trade secrets". Trade secrets are not within scope of this site.

I deleted my answer since your's is clearly more authoritative.
